# Replicate Qualification Example MTurkR

Tags: r, mechanicalturk

I am trying to post a qualification exam to Amazon's mTurk through R using the package `MTurkR` (using OS MAC 10.9).

When I try to replicate the example for the qualification example posted [here](https://github.com/leeper/MTurkR/wiki/Qualification-Tests), I get the following error message:

```
Error in CreateQualificationType(name = "A new coding test 2", description = "Test of coding ability",  : No Namespace specified in 'test'
```

Following from the example, my code and output is as follows:

```
# load QuestionForm and AnswerKey
QuestionForm <- paste0(scan(file="/Users/Desktop/QualExam.xml", what="character", sep="\n"), collapse="")
   >Read 3 items
AnswerKey <- paste0(scan(file="/Users/Desktop/QualExamAnswers.xml", what="character", sep="\n"), collapse="")
   >Read 3 items

# create new QualificationType
newqual <- CreateQualificationType(name="A new coding test 2",
    description="Test of coding ability",
    status="Active",
    test.duration=seconds(hours=1),
    test=QuestionForm,
    answerkey=AnswerKey,
    validate.test=TRUE,
    validate.answerkey=TRUE,
    sandbox=TRUE)
   >Error in CreateQualificationType(name = "A new coding test 2", description = "Test of coding ability",  : No Namespace specified in 'test'
```

I pasted the text exactly from the example to create the `QualExam.xml` and `QualExamAnswers.xml` files.

When I run the revised code, I get the following errors:

```
> QuestionForm <- paste0(readLines("/Users/Desktop/QuestionForm_Example.xml"), collapse = "")
Warning message:
In readLines("/Users/Desktop/QuestionForm_Example.xml") :
  incomplete final line found on '/Users/Desktop/QuestionForm_Example.xml'

>AnswerKey <- paste0(readLines("/User/Desktop/AnswerKey_Example.xml"), collapse = "")
Warning message:
In readLines("/Users/Desktop/AnswerKey_Example.xml") :
  incomplete final line found on '/Users/Desktop/AnswerKey_Example.xml'
>newqual <- CreateQualificationType(name="Classifier: Basic",
     description="This qualification exam tests basic understanding of speech",
     status="Active",
     test.duration=seconds(hours=1),
     test=QuestionForm,
     answerkey=AnswerKey,
     validate.test=TRUE,
     validate.answerkey=TRUE,
     sandbox=sandbox.v)
Error in CreateQualificationType(name = "Classifier: Basic", description = "This qualification exam tests basic understanding of speech",  : 
  No Namespace specified in 'test'
```

My session info is shown below:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: i386-apple-darwin9.8.0/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] MTurkR_0.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.4   RCurl_1.95-4.1 XML_3.98-1.1
```

Please help.

Comment: Did you copy the examples exactly? I'm not able to replicate this exactly. Can you also update your question to include the output of `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: Thanks for editing the link @Thomas. I've revised the question with updated information about the errors I am getting when I try to run this example.

Comment: `QuestionForm_Example.xml` [validates](http://validator.w3.org/check) but is missing DOCTYPE and character encoding. Is that the issue?

Comment: Start by updating your installation of MTurkR. You're a few versions behind the current release. Try again. If that doesn't do it, I suspect this may be a platform-specific issue. I've [opened a ticket](https://github.com/leeper/MTurkR/issues/80) to investigate this further.

Comment: Thanks... this was a problem with version of R and I was not running Xquartz. I've updated my answer to reflect the changes I've made and indicated it is now working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not working because R is not updated (you can update R [here](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/)). You will also have to install [XQuartz 2.7.7](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki/X112.7.7).

The `.xml` files validated and the examples ran properly for me. My `sessionInfo()` information is below:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] MTurkR_0.6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] bitops_1.0-6   digest_0.6.8   RCurl_1.95-4.5 tcltk_3.1.2    tools_3.1.2    XML_3.98-1.1
```